# SQL join left in laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to do this query in laravel query builder but the result is not the same.

```
select u.id as id,
u.name as name,
count(c.user_id) as casos,
cast(SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS pendientes,
cast(SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS enviados
from users u
left join casos c
on c.user_id = u.id
where u.lab_id = 2
and u.admin = 0
group by u.id
```

This is my laravel query:

```
User::select(
            'users.id as id',
            'users.name as name',
            DB::raw("count(casos.user_id) as casos"),
            DB::raw("cast(SUM(CASE WHEN casos.status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS pendientes"),
            DB::raw("cast(SUM(CASE WHEN casos.status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS enviados"),
            'users.created_at as created_at'
        )
        ->leftJoin('casos', 'casos.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('lab_id', 2)
        ->groupBy('user_id');
```

Raw query returns all users even though have no casos, laravel return only users they have casos. what i'm doing wrong in laravel query?

Comment: Got any errors?

Comment: No errors, just different results...

Comment: Maybe you just missed `->where('users.admin', 0)`

Comment: BTW: Why are you using `CAST`? There is no need to cast `1` or `0` to an integer.

Comment: im using CAST because in dev env i using sqllite and returns string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your last lines to:

```
->leftJoin('casos', 'casos.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->where('users.lab_id', 2)
->where('users.admin', 0)
->groupBy('users.id');
```

The condition `u.admin = 0` was missing. And you was grouping by `casos.user_id` instead of `users.id`. You shouldn't group by the right table of a LEFT JOIN.